# SQLAlchemy Automap backref errors

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am new to SQLAlchemy (ORMs in generally) and I am trying to move an existing application on to SQLAlchemy so that we can shift some of the code complexity from the currently existing (and tedious to update) queries, to Python. Unfortunately, I am getting errors immediately after database reflection. Although I can query tables directly, I don't really have direct access to classes, or relationships between classes. Below is an approximately minimal example of what I am trying to do.

Existing postgres table:

```
dev=> \d+ gmt_file
                                        Table "public.gmt_file"
  Column   |     Type     | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 file_id   | integer      | not null  | plain    |              |
       a   | integer      |           | plain    |              | 
       b   | integer      |           | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "gmt_file_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (file_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "gmt_file_a_fk" FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES cmn_user(user_id)
    "gmt_file_b_fk" FOREIGN KEY (b) REFERENCES cmn_user(user_id)
```

SQLAlchemy Application (minimal example):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session,Mapper
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/dev')
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
session = Session(engine,autocommit=True)

session.query(Base.classes.gmt_file).all()
```

From what I can tell so far, this throws a backref error because of the both `a` and `b` having foreign key relationships with the same field in a different table (this happens often in the existing db). I have tried multiple ways of handling this error, including creating custom naming functions (`name_for_scalar_relationship()`, and `name_for_collection_relationship()`), to no avail. Is there a standard way to deal with this, or disable the backref creation during reflection, in SQLAlchemy?

The ultimate goal would be to reflect the db in an automated way, and not have to write custom name mappings for the hundreds of tables that exist currently, but I am at a loss for what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I am not sure if this will be helpful in finding a solution, but I am able to query the table directly using the `__table__` subobject. E.g. `session.query(Base.classes.gmt_file.__table__).all()` does not throw an error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like we get a property name collision using automap when more than one foreign key refers to the same column.

`Base.prepare` allows arguments `name_for_scalar_relationship` and `name_for_collection_relationship`, which take functions used to generate the property names. (See documentation for [`AutomapBase.prepare()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#sqlalchemy.ext.automap.AutomapBase.prepare) and [`name_for_collection_relationship()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#sqlalchemy.ext.automap.name_for_collection_relationship)) I was able to get around the backref error by defining my own function.

Modifying your minimal example:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session,Mapper
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base, name_for_collection_relationship

engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/dev')
Base = automap_base()

def _name_for_collection_relationship(base, local_cls, referred_cls, constraint):
    if constraint.name:
        return constraint.name.lower()
    # if this didn't work, revert to the default behavior
    return name_for_collection_relationship(base, local_cls, referred_cls, constraint)

Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True, name_for_collection_relationship=_name_for_collection_relationship)
session = Session(engine,autocommit=True)

session.query(Base.classes.gmt_file).all()
```

This should hopefully get you your classes with property names `gmt_file_a_fk` and `gmt_file_b_fk`.

This method worked for me. If it doesn't work, you could also try redefining `name_for_scalar_relationship()` similarly.

If you want to override the classes at all, you'll have to make sure to define columns and relationships properly. For example:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class GmtFile(Base):
    __tablename___ = 'gmt_file'

    file_id = Column('file_id', Integer, primary_key=True)

    a = Column('a', Integer, ForeignKey('CmnUser.user_id', name='gmt_file_a'))
    b = Column('b', Integer, ForeignKey('CmnUser.user_id', name='gmt_file_b'))
    # you'll need to define the class CmnUser as well

    # these variable names need to be the same as the ForeignKey names above
    gmt_file_a = relationship('CmnUser', foreign_keys=[a])
    gmt_file_b = relationship('CmnUser', foreign_keys=[b])
```

Comment: It works works for me. 
Thank you, you answered it just in time when I needed it :) .

Comment: I have moved on from SQLAlchemy, so I have not verified this will work in my case. But I am marking it correct because it looks like it could work and it solves at least one other persons problem.